# C#, XNA and Mono. Will it all work?

Tags: c#, xna, mono, cross-platform

If I program in C# with XNA will Mono be ableto compile my program to Mac and Linux reliably?

Answer (score 5):

You will be wanting to use [Monogame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/). It is an opensource solution that you can port your XNA programs onto with almost no code changes at all. And you can easily build for Mac/Linux and even mobile devices.

I have been writing my game for Windows 8 on Monogame and the Farseer Physics Engine recently and it is really easy to port to any device you want.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft XNA requires additional assemblies in your CLR and I don't think Mono comes with anything equivalent. There is, however, a project regarding an XNA implementation for Mono, called [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/), which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: [MonoXna](https://code.google.com/p/monoxna/) also has this goal I believe.

Comment: MonoXna hasn't been updated in a *long* time. All the useful bits were long-ago folded into MonoGame.